# Bubble Sort in Double Linked List - Null Pointer Error

Tags: java, sorting, bubble-sort, doubly-linked-list

```
protected void sortHorseList(int iHorseCount)
{
    int i = 0;
    Horsie currentNode = head;
    Horsie auxNode = new Horsie();
    boolean foundChange = true;
    while(foundChange)
    {
        foundChange = false;
        for(i=0; i<iHorseCount-1; i++)
        {
            if (currentNode.getHorseValue() > currentNode.getNext().getHorseValue())
            {
                auxNode.setHorseValue(currentNode.getHorseValue());
                currentNode.setHorseValue(currentNode.getNext().getHorseValue());
                currentNode.getNext().setHorseValue(auxNode.getHorseValue());
                foundChange = true;
            }
            currentNode = currentNode.getNext();
        }
    }
}
```

This code **displays a null pointer error** when running the main program. I am a novice at data structure, and I'm hoping to solve this problem with your help guys! Please teach me how to use **bubble sort** in a **doubly linked list**...HEEELP!

Comment: Please tag with relevant programming language.

Comment: Which line throws the NullPointerException?

Comment: Homework? Nobody sorts linked lists, and nobody uses bubble sort outside academe.

Answer (score 1):

When you get to the end of the list, you aren't checking to see if a next element exists. Thus when you attempt to access it's value, you get the null reference exception.  Your inner loop should look something like

```
   Horsie currentNode = head;
   Horsie nextNode = currentNode != null ? currentNode.getNext() : null;
   while (currentNode != null && nextNode != null)
    {
        if (currentNode.getHorseValue() > nextNode.getHorseValue())
        {
            currentNode = Swap(head,currentNode,nextNode);
            foundChange = true;
        }
        else
        {
            currentNode = nextNode;
        }
        nextNode = currentNode.getNext();
    }
```

Where `Swap(Horsie current, Horsie next)` exchanges the place of `current` and `next` in the list and, optionally, updates the head if `current` was the head node.

I'll also note that you *do* want to swap the nodes in the list rather than swap the values between nodes unless you are sure that your list holds the only references to the node objects. If you don't you run the risk of having an object held by some other class unexpectedly mutate because you've changed its value during the sort.

Comment: Can you please help me with the Swap method? How can I start the method?

Comment: @VincentSy - you just need to fix up the (forward) pointers so that `current`'s parent points to `next`, `next` points to `current`, and `current` points to `next`'s previous follower. Similarly with the back pointers. You will also need to handle the special cases where `current` is the `head` element as well as when `next` is the tail.

Comment: How can I do it? Can you give me the codes for it? (BEGINNER) :\